# invalid group function in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from details where sal=max(sal);
```

I use this but I get error..What is the mistake in this query .I know

- `select Max(sal) from table;`
- `select * from details where sal=max(sal);`

are correct queries but I need to know what is the mistake in my query.

Answer (score 5):

You intend to compare each row's salary against the maximum value in that table.  Then use a subquery to determine that maximum salary:

```
SELECT *
FROM details
WHERE sal = (SELECT MAX(sal) FROM details)
```

This query would return *all* records having the max salary, which could be more than one in the case of a tie.  If you are certain that there be only a single record having the maximum salary, then the following would also work:

```
SELECT *
FROM details
ORDER BY sal DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: the mistake is we should not use where with Group functions